# Using "SUMIF" array for particular values(date) only

Tags: excel

I have a log from restaurant of about last 4 months.
I have to calculate the total number of sold Products on **Particular Date**. 
Here is the Sample format :

```
Date|    Time |   Product Code | Name |     Price      Sold Unit
7/2/2018 13:00    0101           XXX           100       4 
7/2/2018 15:00    0101           XXX           100       6
7/3/2018 12:00    0101           ZZZ           100       4 
7/3/2018 19:00    0101           ZZZ           100       4
```

Now I can use SUMIF and find out the total XXX and ZZZ sold. Which will equivalent to XXX = 10 and ZZZ = 8 .
But I want to calculate (SUM IF ) total on particular date which is of 7/2 and 7/3 .
I can use filter tab and select date and calculate. But the problem is log is of 30-31 Days . So it will take some time and I have about 3 months data to calculate. 
Is it possible to calculate without using Filter tab for particular Date ?

Original File[Report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xk75xca2uKU09JLq1WLkmUPQ4OALwfvF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Use `SUMIFS`, with the date as the additional criterion.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have used SUMIF but It calculates through whole date and adds up total of whole 1 month. I want each day sumif(total)

Comment: Now I'm not entirely sure what you want, but if you want the total number of products sold on 7/2/2108, use the date as your criterion in `SUMIF`. If you want the total number of XXX products sold on 7/2/18, use `SUMIFS` with those the date and name as your criteria. Or use a pivot table.

Comment: My Point is that I have Date of 7-1-2018 to 7-31-2018 .
If I use SUMIF on individual Product. It will calculate from 1st date to 31st date. Lets Say On Day 1 , XXX Sold 5 . Day 2 XX sold 15 .. I want in this sequence till 31st date. Currently I am having whole total.. Lets say 10000 product sold from 1st to 31st .

Comment: Have you tried `SUMIFS` yet? `SUMIFS` is not the same as `SUMIF`.

Comment: I used SUMIF . Here is the link of google drive I have uploaded the original file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xk75xca2uKU09JLq1WLkmUPQ4OALwfvF/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data span from col A to col F. Try this.. and adjust accordingly..

```
=SUMIFS(F:F,D:D,"XXX",A:A,DATE(2018,7,2))
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: I have used the code for SUMIF. I am not sure of above formulas insertment. I have edit the main file, and added the link to original file, Can you once take a look?

Comment: I use the same formula.. [here](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/EarvSAFhIMdAmsN8PPKwKnEBIWZ4yTDENv-Z52eD_m1b_A?e=ATInGj) is the result.. at Sheet2. noticed that there is I'm using `sumifs()` .. not `sumif()` .

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I wanted and I tried it too. But sumif and sumifs looks different in entering criteria and all. Like here is my array format for SUMIF
`=SUMIF($F$40777:$F$41722,F40777,$K$40777:$K$41722)` <br> F contains Sum Code and K contains Product Sold. And how do I enter these conditions in SUMIFS. I downloaded and open your files but I cannot click on fx button upon selecting cells that have arrays in it. + you seems to have select product name for calculation.

Comment: You're right.. I did..  ( : in `Sheet1!C3` .. the formula is.. `=SUMIFS('Trn - Copy'!K:K,'Trn - Copy'!I:I,Sheet1!B3,'Trn - Copy'!A:A,Sheet1!A3)` .. goto excel help file to get more info on sumifs ..

Comment: For `sumif()` , the syntax is... `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])` . and for `sumifs()` .. the syntax is... `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)` || So, using `sumif()` you may only define 1 criteria and using `sumifs()` you may define more than one criteria for the summation.

Comment: Still having trouble arrays applying arrays to it . :( Used the same criteria as yours. But it gives me #value error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178054/discussion-between-p-phidot-and-).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your above formula was right all the way . I was confused but you helped me in chat. Thank you very much. 5 star help :)